# Как через jmeter запустить определенное количество пользователей на модуль

Tags: jmeter

Как через jmeter запустить определенное количество пользователей на модуль (300 модулей одновременно должны быть запущены разными пользователями). Как это можно проверить?

Answer (score 0):

Мы не очень понимаем что такое "модуль", что касается JMeter и распределения нагрузки, можно рассмотреть следующие варианты:

1. Использовать отдельные [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) для каждого "модуля"

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Использовать одну Thread Group и разные [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) для распределения нагрузки

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Использовать плагин, например [Weighted Switch Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-weighted-switch-controller-the-ultimate-guide), он более удобен и гибок чем Throughput Controller:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]